# Do kinect topics depend on drivers

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, rosbag, libfreenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I happened to have downloaded a bag file of Kinect which was recorded with the help of libfreenect driver. If i develop a node which is for kinect and that uses Openni driver. Will there be differences in the type of topics that are created by both drivers in terms of images and point clouds?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41099/do-kinect-topics-depend-on-drivers/) by [Karan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2995/karan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 263 on 2012-08-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer your question directly, yes, the different kinect drivers have different ROS APIs (meaning the topics they publish are different). You can take a look at the wiki pages for the different drivers ([kinect_camera](http://www.ros.org/wiki/kinect_camera) which uses libfreenect, and [openni_camera](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera), which uses the openni drivers) to compare.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Karan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2995/karan/) on 2012-08-10**:
Thanks it really helped. From this i draw that when i write a node for kinect running on different drivers  in ros i should pay attention to the topic names. So that the subscription is not hampered.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whenever using a bag file you may play that file

[rosbag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Tutorials/Recording%20and%20playing%20back%20data)

- and then use rostopic to find revelent info

Update: Lorenz is correct, you can simply use rosbag info

---

Originally posted by [gpsinghsandhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2834/gpsinghsandhu/) with karma: 231 on 2012-08-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sanket_Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2789/sanket_kumar/) on 2012-08-10**:
it helped me thnx bro :-)

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-10**:
Much simpler: just use rosbag info. It will tell you the topics and types stored in the bag.

**Comment by [Karan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2995/karan/) on 2012-08-10**:
So in conclusion, you always have the same topics in a .bag file of kinect regardless of being recorded on a laptop having either libfreenect or openni driver? The main question being do drivers affect topics in a bag file.?

**Comment by [gpsinghsandhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2834/gpsinghsandhu/) on 2012-08-10**:
You use the rosbag info command and display the output in your question and using that I will be able to help as I have only worked with openni drivers.